# Accessing elements with std::vector::data()

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

For this piece of code I am using the [`data()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) method of the vector to access its elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector (5);

  int* p = myvector.data();

  *p = 10;
  ++p;
  *p = 20;
  p[2] = 100;

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Which generates

```
myvector contains: 10 20 0 100 0
```

The question is why `p[2]` is 0? Assuming `myvector.data()` is a pointer to the first element (index 0), then `p[0]` is 10 which fine. `++p` points to the next element which is `p[1]` and that is 20 which is also fine. Now, `p[2]` is the next element after `p[1]`. So, the sequence should be `10 20 100`. Whats is the mistake here?

Comment: `"++p points to the next element ..."` and also increments `p` itself.

Comment: Did you confuse `myvector[2]` and `p[2]`? The latter is indexed relative to `p` itself.

Comment: Try the same code but with an array and a pointer, you'll find exactly the same result.

Comment: `p` was initially equal to `&myvector[0]`, but after incrementing is equivalent to `&myvector[1]`.   `p[2]`  is therefore equivalent to `myvector[3]`.      Since all elements of `myvector` were initialised to zero, and `myvector[2]` is not changed, it is still zero.

Comment: Right I confused that with myvector. Thanks.

Comment: Also, note that C++ discourages you to do (complex) raw pointer arithmetic. The data method is usually only used for interaction with legacy API's that still require a raw pointer. Most other code should use iterators, or range based for loops

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You incremented `p` by 1 and then wrote into `p[2]`, which effectively now is `myvector[3]`.

Writing to `p[1]` would write to the field adjacent to `*p`.

Answer (score 8):

You initialize the pointer `p` to point to `myvector[0]`.

Then you increment `p`, so now it points to `myvector[1]`.

If we draw it out then it's something like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| myvector[0] | myvector[1] | myvector[2] | myvector[3] | myvector[4] |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
                ^
                |
                p
```

Now the important part: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`.

That means `p[2]` in your code is the same as `*(p + 2)`. And since `p` is pointing to the second element of the vector, `p + 2` will point to the fourth.

Again lets draw it out:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| myvector[0] | myvector[1] | myvector[2] | myvector[3] | myvector[4] |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
                ^             ^             ^             ^
                |             |             |             |
                p             p + 1         p + 2         p + 3
```

So when you write to `p[2]` then it's the same as writing to `myvector[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets refactor your code to make `p` always point to the first element:

```
*p = 10;
//++p;  // removed this line and replaced p with p+1 below
*(p+1) = 20;
(p+1)[2] = 100;
```

Next, consider that `a[b]` for built in `[]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a+b)`, hence the last line is `*(p+1+2)` is `*(p+3)` is `p[3]`.

After you incremented `p` once, the subsript index is with respect to the updated pointer. `x[2]` adds `2` to `x` and then dereferences it. Usually `x` points to first element of an array, but yours points to the second.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++17 Standard (8.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
> a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of
> type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other
> shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type. The
> result is of type “T”. The type “T” shall be a completely-defined
> object type. The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to
> *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 8.3 and 8.7 for details of * and + and 11.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ] , except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an
> lvalue and an xvalue otherwise. The expression E1 is sequenced before
> the expression E2.

So as the pointer `p` initially points to the first element of the vector then after incrementing the pointer `p`

```
++p;
*p = 20;
```

it now points to the second element of the vector. And at last the expression
`p[2]` in this statement

```
p[2] = 100;
```

that is equivalent to the expression *( p + 2 ) yields the forth element of the vector.

If to introduce an intermediate pointer before this statement

```
++p;
```

like

```
int *q = p'
```

then you have that the expression `p[2]` evaluated like `*( p + 2 )` is equivalent to `*( ( q + 1 ) + 2 )` that is the same as `*( q + 3 )`. So the fourth element of the vector is updated.